# Google cloud platform: How the life cycle versioning works in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working in the GCP console and trying to copy the `file stores` data to the `google cloud storage`
This is the command I am using:

```
gsutil rsync -r /fileserver/demo/dir1 gs://corp-bucket/dir1

/fileserver/demo/dir1: mount point directory where the file store is mounted
corp-bucket: google cloud bucket
corp-bucket/dir1: folder I created in the bucket
```

**This is also working fine this command copying the data from the file store to the storage bucket but I want to know is there any way to to keep the versioning data, Like if I copy the updated data/code the old data/code should be archived**

There is one feature in the bucket called `lifecycle rule` and number of newer version but I am not sure how it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so about versioning data, you can [enable object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#enable) on your bucket so that you have various versions of your objects. I suggest to check more about object versioning in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning), but basically you will be storing past versions identified by generation and metageneration. In this case your billing could increase as you will be storing different objects per version.

In order to decrease this you can use [lifecycle rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), this will also be helpful for explaining here what are these.

Lifecycle rules are rules that works as triggers, you can set conditions and if an object meets the condition(s) then you can set actions in order to delete or modify the storage class.

There are various examples for this at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#deletion-example), but I believe the next example could be great for the inquiries that you have:

Example
To delete noncurrent versions of objects older than 35 days:

- Select the Delete object action.
- Select the Age condition, and enter a value of 35.
- Select the Live state condition, and choose the Noncurrent option.

In this case you could use the lifecycle rules to make the version of your objects to be deleted after some time (and in this case you could save some money depending of the type of storage class).

Hope this helps you with the inquiries that you had.